# Issue with Bootstrap Accordion for Partial View with dynamic added Partial Views

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have an issue with implementing bootstrap accordion on a partial view with dynamically generated partial views within. For some reason the accordion
will not collapse when I click the icon to collapse it - instead it doesnt collapse it just turns the background of the li tag blue.

My partial view looks like the following:

```
   <li class="thesection" id="accordion">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h2><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span> Section</h2>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Section Name</span>
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(t => t.SectionName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(t => t.IndexOrder)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Section Guide</span>
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(t => SectionGuide, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="delete">Delete Section</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @Html.Partial("AreaSectionItemsPartial", Model.TemplateCompanySectionItems)

                    </div>
         </div>
    </li>
```

The onpageload function on the parent View looks like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#accordion').accordion({
            collapsible:true
        })
});
```

Any ideas why my accordion is unresponsive? Am I going to need to modify my Views layout? Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is you partial being loaded dynamically (e.g. loaded via ajax)? What, if any errors do you get in the browser console?

Comment: It's being loaded with an ajax call. I'm thinking that it might not be the partial views that is the issue but instead my layout - in hind sight I don't think it was worth mentioning the dynamic content aspect. Is there anything can you can see with my above code that could be causing the items inside class .thesection to not collapse? @StephenMuecke?

Comment: If the content is loaded dynamically you need to attach the plugin after the content is loaded (e.g. in the ajax success callback)